# Which classifier for window (窗户) is regularly used?

Tags: ambiguity, measure-word

The dictionary lists two classifiers for window (窗户) 个 and 扇. Are both of these in common usage? If so is there any difference in the register? Does one sound more formal, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

一扇窗户 refers to a window on the wall, while 一个窗户 refers to the object (frame and glass) of the window.

In most cases, 一扇窗户 is the only correct choice, 一个窗户 should not be used even in everyday speaking.

However, 一个窗户 is more appropriate when:

- the window is not installed on the wall yet.
- the window refers to something in computer interface (窗口).
- the window refers to a car window.
- the window (窗口) refers to a counter (in a bank etc.).

Comment: When you say "almost"... Does it mean there are cases where you can use it?

Comment: If you Google "一个窗户" (with the quotes), you can find results. People use it when they do not care the grammar. I just realized that it is the correct one when "窗户" refers to a window in your computer interface.

Comment: Why don't you include that in your answer and maybe you expand on it?

Comment: I made some changes.

Comment: Not really, `窗户` is invalid for computer interface window, use `窗口` for that.

Comment: Yes. 窗口 is more valid for computer interface window, but people still use 窗户 (by mistake).